# Chainlink VRF not returning

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I'm using Chainlink VRF to get a random number, however, I keep getting

```
Although one or more Error Occurred [out of gas] Contract Execution Completed
```

[On the callback transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc4e46c63831d3a0bcba2255763c542432ff8c0edb9c51fefa86ee3aaa8963e4a), what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/) has gas limits on callback. Reference the documentation to see exactly how much for each network.